# Android Sliding Tabs crashes ( logcat: Can't convert to color: type=0x1 )

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am trying to make sliding tabs with icons. I have written the code using google's [slidingtablayout.java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [slidingtabstrip.java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java)

The issue I am encountering is that my app is getting crashed in my phones (tested on kitkat and lollipop). However, I do not know why tablets are supporting the app and it runs flawlessly on my tablet (ICS), tablet emulator and bluestacks.

Logcat:

```
06-04 03:45:42.970    3254-3254/com.easyaccom.abhishek.slidingtabswiper E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.easyaccom.abhishek.slidingtabswiper, PID: 3254
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.easyaccom.abhishek.slidingtabswiper/com.easyaccom.abhishek.slidingtabswiper.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:404)
        at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:3683)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:85)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
```

Here is my implementation for the same. Along with layouts. The minsdk is 11 and target is 22. Please let me know the reason for the issue.

Apart from Mainactivity.java class, I have SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java

activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.easyaccom.abhishek.slidingtabswiper.MainActivity">

        <com.easyaccom.abhishek.slidingtabswiper.SlidingTabLayout
               android:id="@+id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/pager"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               />


       </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Custom tabview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="8dp"
  android:id="@+id/tabController">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tabImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tabText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"/>
```

fragment_my.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/position"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:text=" The page Number is 1"
android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

colors.xml (logcat shows issues with one of my colors I think):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#03A9F4</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0288D1</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryLight">#B3E5FC</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF5722</color>
<color name="colorHighlight">#B6B6B6</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryText">#212121</color>
<color name="colorSecondaryText">#727272</color>
<color name="colorDivider">#B6B6B6</color>
<color name="colorba">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you provide the logs plz

Comment: @NaderAyyad I am updating my Android studio, I will post it asap.

Comment: @NadarAyyad Added Logcat output pls help. Also hover over the logcat image to get the rest part of the log  invisible part of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the answer to this question is very simple. I do not know for what reason but android studio by default had added colors.xml for 820dp wide devices (tablets) only. So there was no colors.xml for phones. It did not give me any error at compile time because there already was colors.xml off course for tablets not phones. Just as I added another colors.xml with same name, the issue was resolved. I think android studio needs to fix this probably they will in next updates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be one of the colors you're setting. Unfortunately the logcat image is cut off, but the exception type is `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` .

edit: Try to comment out (or delete) this portion to see if it's the culprit:

```
mTabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer(){

    @Override
    public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    }
});`
```

Comment: Cut off part basically says java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x1

Comment: I added the colors.xml file in my question. Please check

Comment: I did but it doesn't change the case. No change in logcat as well.

Comment: Also removed the background color in app_bar.xml, no change in issue.

Comment: Same with fragment_my.xml

Comment: Can you paste your logcat? Instead of the screenshot

Comment: I am just implementing simple tabs with icons and we have no other option than material design at moment.  So all that I am left with is color issue? WTH?

Answer (score 0):

hi i faced the same issue my problem was that android studio created a color.xml in values-w820dp so i changed to the project prespective and then copied colors.xml to values folder and it solv